# UTF-16 PHP String to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, utf

I have a string on a variable `$str` after successfully decrypting AES cipher with `mcrypt_decrypt`. If I try to print `str` to screen, I do notice that it has a blank space between each letter, that actually is a `NULL termination (\x00)` given by `UTF-16` character encoding.

`Array
(
    [1] => 33
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 34
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 35
    [6] => 0
    ...
)`

I've tried many ways to turn it into `UTF-8` but I failed. What can I do?

Comment: you should always add what you have tried already, to help us help you :D

Comment: What have you tried to convert? Maybe ``iconv`` will help to solve http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8" , "UTF-16LE");
```